# How to create a web application which works for both web browser and android app

Tags: android, web-applications

**I have a little knowledge in developing web application.**

but I need to explore something like application which works in web browser and android app.I have idea that how both works separately.

**1. Web application**

**2. Android App**

but i don't have an idea how to code for application which works in web browser and android app.

**Whether I need to code for both separately or there is any method or technology to work with it.**

*If so help me out with a simple Example .. or reference.*

Comment: If you don't want to code in Android, you can try Ionic framework.


https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

The concept you're looking for is called "Progressive Web App". I can't tell you how it works becase it would be a full tutorial. However, I can point you in the right direction.
Take a look at:

https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/

You might also want to:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/android-app-installs

Good luck on your learning jurney.

Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: 100% I m not sure that this is what I m looking for ... But for an example let's consider an e-commerce website (Flipkart ) the same site is opened in desktop and mobile app (Android).

There the content of the same mobile looks in different perspective.

The data and details comes from single server how they have coded for

Web and Android app 

Whether my understanding is right ..
And how to proceed further 

But not for e-commerce website with a little simpler example

Comment: This concept is used by many companies, such as Trivago and Airbnb (I think), to have an app that matches the website.You only need to code it once, and it works perfectly on both platforms. The fact that the data in both comes from the same server is not core to the concept, because you can do that with completly different apps as well. Here is another reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/progressive-web-apps/